# shiny: How to print an entire Tabset() with plots only when actionButton() is clicked?

Tags: r, plot, shiny, tabs, shinyapps

I am completely new to `shiny`, which I am trying to learn by building this simple `app`.

It currently prints two different `ggplots` based on specific `input`-values after the `actionButton()` is clicked. However, I find the graphic a bit off when the two plots are printed next to each other.

**Question:** how can I integrate a `Tabset` that *only* prints when the `actionButton()` is clicked? The Tabset should contain two tabs - one with each plot.

My app currently looks like this

[image]

---

Which prints the two plots when the `actionButton()` is clicked:

[image]

---

I would like something like this to print:

[image]

---

and

[image]

---

In `ui`, I tried multiple variations of:

```
tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Plot1", plotOutput("surv_plot")), .....
```

Without the intended output.

My `shinyapp` is written with (general comments and script improvements are most welcome):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(survminer)
library(shinycustomloader)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(


  useShinyjs(),
  br(),
  titlePanel(
    h1("Text", align="center")
    ),

  br(), 

  div(HTML("Text, <em>et al.</em>: <strong>Text</strong>" )), 
  div(HTML("DOI: " )),


  br(), br(),


  fluidRow(

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        sliderInput("n_fjernet", "Lymph Nodal Yield", 
                    min = 2, max = 120, value = 40)
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        sliderInput("n_sygdom", "Number of positive lymph nodes", 
                    min = 0, max = 40, value = 0)
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        radioButtons("ecs", "Extracapsular extension", c("No","Yes"))
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        radioButtons("contra_pos", "Neck involvement", c("Contra.","Ipsi."))
      )
    )

  ),

  fluidRow(align="center", br(), actionBttn("do", "Submit", style = "material-flat")),


  br(), br(), 
  h3(textOutput("starttext"), align="center"),
                           tags$head(tags$style("#starttext{color: grey20;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                                 font-style: plain;
                                 }"
                )
  ),


  fluidRow(br(),

    column(12, align="center", 
           withLoader(plotOutput("load_plot", width = "1%", height="10px"), 
                      type="html", loader="dnaspin")
    ),

    column(6, align="center", 
           textOutput("nomtext"),
           tags$head(tags$style("#nomtext{color: grey20;
                                 font-size: 40px;
                                 font-style: plain;
                                 }"
                          )
           ),

           plotOutput("surv_nom", width = "105%", height="600px")
    ),



    column(6, align="center", 
           textOutput("survtext"),
           tags$head(tags$style("#survtext{color: grey20;
                                 font-size: 40px;
                                 font-style: plain;
                                 }"
                      )
                ),

           plotOutput("surv_plot", width = "95%", height="600px")
       )
  )

)







server <- function(input, output, session) {



  observeEvent(input[["n_sygdom"]], {
    if(input[["n_sygdom"]] < 1){
      disable("ecs")
      disable("contra_pos")
    }else{
      enable("ecs")
      enable("contra_pos")
    }
  })




  rvs <- reactiveValues(n_sygdom = 0)


  observeEvent(input$n_sygdom, {
    if ((input$n_sygdom == 0)) {
      updateRadioButtons(session, "ecs", selected = "No")
      updateRadioButtons(session, "contra_pos", selected = "Contra.")
    }
    rvs$n_sygdom <- input$n_sygdom
  })




  observe(
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "n_sygdom",
      max = min(40, input$n_fjernet),
      value = min(input$n_fjernet, input$n_sygdom)
    )
  )



  reactive_nom_text <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    paste0("Individualized pN-score")

  })

  output$nomtext <- renderText({
    reactive_nom_text()

  })




  reactive_surv_text <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    paste0("Survival probability")

  })

  output$survtext <- renderText({
    reactive_surv_text()

  })




  reactive_start <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    paste0("Such patient yield a pN-score of ")
  })

  output$starttext <- renderText({
    reactive_start()

  })




  reactive_surv_plot <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(0:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) 

  })


  output$surv_plot <- renderPlot({


    reactive_surv_plot()

  })





  reactive_surv_nom <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(0:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) 


  })


  output$surv_nom <- renderPlot({

   reactive_surv_nom()

  })



  reactive_load <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(0:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) 


  })

  output$load_plot <- renderPlot({

    reactive_load()

  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uiOutput` in the `ui` and `renderUI` in the `server` to generate a tabset with two tabs only when the button is clicked.

Here's your example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(survminer)
library(shinycustomloader)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(


  useShinyjs(),
  br(),
  titlePanel(
    h1("Text", align="center")
  ),

  br(), 

  div(HTML("Text, <em>et al.</em>: <strong>Text</strong>" )), 
  div(HTML("DOI: " )),


  br(), br(),


  fluidRow(

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        sliderInput("n_fjernet", "Lymph Nodal Yield", 
                    min = 2, max = 120, value = 40)
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        sliderInput("n_sygdom", "Number of positive lymph nodes", 
                    min = 0, max = 40, value = 0)
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        radioButtons("ecs", "Extracapsular extension", c("No","Yes"))
      )
    ),

    column(
      3,
      wellPanel(
        style = "height:150px", 
        radioButtons("contra_pos", "Neck involvement", c("Contra.","Ipsi."))
      )
    )

  ),

  fluidRow(align="center", br(), actionBttn("do", "Submit", style = "material-flat")),


  br(), br(), 
  h3(textOutput("starttext"), align="center"),
  tags$head(tags$style("#starttext{color: grey20;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                                 font-style: plain;
                                 }"
  )
  ),


  fluidRow(br(),

           column(12, align="center", 
                  withLoader(plotOutput("load_plot", width = "1%", height="10px"), 
                             type="html", loader="dnaspin"),
           uiOutput("test")
           )

  )

)







server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$do, {
    output$test <- renderUI({
      tabsetPanel(id = "something",
                  tabPanel(title = "Panel 1",
                           plotOutput("surv_nom")),
                  tabPanel(title = "Panel 2",
                           plotOutput("surv_plot"))
      )
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input[["n_sygdom"]], {
    if(input[["n_sygdom"]] < 1){
      disable("ecs")
      disable("contra_pos")
    }else{
      enable("ecs")
      enable("contra_pos")
    }
  })

  rvs <- reactiveValues(n_sygdom = 0)

  observeEvent(input$n_sygdom, {
    if ((input$n_sygdom == 0)) {
      updateRadioButtons(session, "ecs", selected = "No")
      updateRadioButtons(session, "contra_pos", selected = "Contra.")
    }
    rvs$n_sygdom <- input$n_sygdom
  })

  observe(
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "n_sygdom",
      max = min(40, input$n_fjernet),
      value = min(input$n_fjernet, input$n_sygdom)
    )
  )



  reactive_nom_text <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    paste0("Individualized pN-score")

  })

  output$nomtext <- renderText({
    reactive_nom_text()

  })




  reactive_surv_text <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    paste0("Survival probability")

  })

  output$survtext <- renderText({
    reactive_surv_text()

  })




  reactive_start <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    paste0("Such patient yield a pN-score of ")
  })

  output$starttext <- renderText({
    reactive_start()

  })




  reactive_surv_plot <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(0:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) 

  })


  output$surv_plot <- renderPlot({


    reactive_surv_plot()

  })





  reactive_surv_nom <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(0:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) 


  })


  output$surv_nom <- renderPlot({

    reactive_surv_nom()

  })



  reactive_load <- eventReactive(input$do, {

    set.seed(1)
    df <- data.frame(y=sample(1:17,1000, replace=TRUE), x=sample(0:100, 1000, replace=TRUE))

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) 


  })

  output$load_plot <- renderPlot({

    reactive_load()

  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @bretauv. Thank you very much.